# Forcing in culture 24h and 12h time format

Tags: c#, time, windows-phone, timepicker, culture

As in title. I tried this:

```
CultureInfo ti = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;

if (SettingsApp[0].TimeFormat == 0)
{
    ti.DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern = "HH:mm";
}
else
{
    ti.DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern = "hh:mm tt";
}

Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ti;
```

I want to change the time format on toolkit timepicker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have a [System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker).

If so, you need not change the culture on the current thread - you can just use the [CustomFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.customformat) property, e.g.

```
public void SetCustomFormat(DateTimePicker dateTimePicker, bool twentyFourHour)
{
   dateTimePicker.ShowUpDown = true;
   dateTimePicker.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
   dateTimePicker.CustomFormat = twentyFourHour ? "HH:mm" : "hh:mm tt";
}
```

**Note:**

I've set [`ShowUpDown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.showupdown) to `true`:

> When the ShowUpDown property is set to true, a spin button control (also known as an up-down control), rather than a drop-down calendar, is used to adjust time values.